# Crop saving Bitmap

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to capture a photo, then crop it. So basically, I start camera Intent, then I start crop intent.

As I can't pass a big bitmap through "onActivityResult" data, I created a URI to save the image directly to SDCard, but for some reason, it's being saved on the emulator, but not on a real device. 
(I mean, the CROP isn't saved on the real device. )

This is the code:

```
File resultingFile;
Bitmap fotoCreada;
Uri uriFoto;
```

Camera Intent:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/PictureFolder/");
folder.mkdirs();
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
resultingFile=new File(folder.toString() + "/"+currentDateandTime+".jpg");
this.uriFoto=Uri.fromFile(resultingFile);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.uriFoto);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
```

Then I retrieve result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //Si venim de la camera
    if( requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == -1) { //-1 = TOT HA ANAT BE.
        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resultingFile.getPath());
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        matrix.postScale(0.5f,0.5f);
        Bitmap photoRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        //Desem foto rotada.
        this.fotoCreada=photoRotated;
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.resultingFile.getPath());
            this.fotoCreada.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        performCrop();
    }
```

So I call performCrop();

```
private void performCrop() {
    try {
        Log.d("debugging","Estic a crop. La foto és:"+this.uriFoto);
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(this.uriFoto, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 600);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 600);
        //cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("ouput", this.uriFoto);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent,1234);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.cont, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see:

```
cropIntent.putExtra("ouput", this.uriFoto);
```

Basically tells to Output the crop to that URI.
The URI is correct, as I've debugged it (LogCat):

> Estic a crop. La foto és: file:///mnt/sdcard/PictureFolder/20130123_223058.jpg

And then, I'm back to activity result:

```
[... previous onactivityresult]
if (requestCode == 1234 && resultCode == -1){
        Log.d("debugging","Ha acabat el croop.");
        Uri imageUri = this.uriFoto;
        try {
            Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.cont.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            this.fotoCreada=photo;
            ((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fotoCapturada)).setImageBitmap(this.fotoCreada);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resultingFile.getPath());     
    }
```

**But what I end up with, is displaying (setImageBitmap(this.fotoCreada);) the captured image from camera, but not the cropped picture. This happens on real device, but not on Emulator!**

I tried to explain the best way I could. Feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: "then I start crop intent" -- there is no "crop intent" in Android. You are relying upon an undocumented `Intent` action from an application that does not exist on all devices. Please do not use this.

Comment: What should I use instead of com.android.camera.action.CROP? Probably this is the issue that I'm facing. Crop works on emulator, but not on real device. I've tried to search about letting users crop image, and all I can find is using the intent I've used above. I'd appreciate some tips.

Comment: I just wrote a blog post on this, which contains links to four open source image cropping libraries: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Can't find any usage example in those libraries...

Comment: AFAIK, you use them the same as what you are using, except that instead of that `com.android` `Intent` action, you create an `Intent` pointing to an activity supplied by the library. Or, read the source code. Or, use a search engine and find other libraries -- the search that turned up those four took me about two minutes.

Comment: Do you have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest?